# Magento - getting category custom attribute value

Tags: magento

How to get current custom category attribute value in product list view?
I'm trying like this

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getAttributes();
```

And I see it's there but how to get it?
My custom attribue name is catalog_pdf

Also tryed in this way, but get nothing:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getAttribute('catalog_category','catalog_pdf');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.
If you are int the product list then you should have the current category in

```
Mage::registry('current_category');
```

So do like this:

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($category){ //this is necessary in case you are in a product listing that is's not a category
   $value = $category->getData('catalog_pdf');//catalog_pdf is the attribute code
   //or
   //$value = $category->getCatalogPdf();
}
```

Comment: you're saving my live. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$id = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId();

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getCode()->getId())->load($id);
echo $category->getData('catalog_pdf');
//or
echo $category->getCatalogPdf();
```

Edited to include missing get